# MySQL AES Encryption - Is it good idea to store 3rd Party Auth Tokens using AES Encryption?

Tags: mysql, security, cryptography, aes, access-token

I need some advice on MySQL AES Encryption. 
I'm developing an application which connects to various 3rd-Party APIs and retrieves the Access Tokens for the application users. These Access Tokens are long-lived and will be used in offline mode for performing a bunch of tasks. 
My Question is that since Access Tokens have much privileges on a user's account, is it a good idea to store them using AES or some similar Encryption ? 
Is there any other better approach to secure these tokens?

Comment: Where do you intend to store the encryption key?

Comment: Well, since I have just one server for this application, so most probably the key would have to be stored there.

do you have any better solution?

Comment: Questions about security or cryptography that do not include a programming problem are off-topic for Stack Overflow. I have voted to close.

Comment: Further to @DuncanJones point, you might consider [security.se].

Comment: Thanks @DuncanJones I'll keep that in mind and resubmit the question at IT Security..